# Inkscape - Taking Difference of Wrong Object

Tags: inkscape

How do I control which object Inkscape takes the difference from?
These are my two objects:
[image]

But when I take the difference, I get:
[image]
Instead of the circle missing the blue parts.

Comment: With a difference boolean operation, the object on top punches a hole in the object below. So your objects must be in the wrong order. Bring the blue object to the top of the stack.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want A-B bring to front object B or send to back object A.